# Unable to Use Child Component in parent component

Tags: angular

I am unable to refer child 
in parent even i have defined the child component definition in module.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-cockpit',
  template: '<p>cockpit-works</p>'
})
```

app.Module.ts

```
  @NgModule({
 declarations: [
  AppComponent,
  CockpitComponent, // Here its defined
  ServerCollectionComponent
  ],
```

app.component.ts

```
 @Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 template: `<h1>Parent Component</h1>
            <div><app-cockpit></app-cockpit>
            </div>`,
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
```

I am able to get Html of cockpit.component.ts

Comment: Can you provide a stackblitz?

Comment: Its unclear, can you please rephrase the question and add more context.

Comment: sir, i am unable to get child component.into parent

Comment: What error message do you have?

Comment: thats the main problem i am not getting any error